# How to convert a Variant array to a Range?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I have a 2D array of type `Variant`. The size and values that populate the array are generated based on data within a worksheet. Further processing is required on this array, the primary being the interpolation of several values. I am using this [interpolation function](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=64100) (I know about excel equivalent functions but a design choice was made not to use them) . The problem I am having is the that the Interpolation function requires a Range object.

I have already tried modifying the function to use a Variant (`r as Variant`) argument. The following line `nR = r.Rows.Count` can be replaced with `nR = Ubound(r)`. While this works, I would also like to use this function normally within any worksheet and not change the function in any way.

```
Sub DTOP()
    Dim term_ref() As Variant
    ' snip '
    ReDim term_ref(1 To zeroRange.count, 1 To 2)

    ' values added to term_ref '

    ' need to interpolate x1 for calculated y1 '
    x1 = Common.Linterp(term_ref, y1) 
End Sub
```

**Interpolation Function**

```
Function Linterp(r As Range, x As Double) As Double
    Dim lR As Long, l1 As Long, l2 As Long
    Dim nR As Long

    nR = r.Rows.Count
    ' snipped for brevity ' 
End Function
```

How do I convert my in-memory variant array to a Range so that it can be used for the interpolate function? (without outputting to a WorkSheet)

**Answer**

In short, the answer is you can't. A Range object must reference a worksheet.

The changed interpolation function checks the `TypeName` of the argument and sets the value of `nR` accordingly. Not the prettiest solution.

As a note, the `VarType` function proved useless in this situation since both `VarType(Variant())` and `VarType(Range)` returned the same value (i.e vbArray) and could not be used to disambiguate an array from a range

```
Function Linterp(r As Variant, x As Variant) As Double
    Dim lR As Long, l1 As Long, l2 As Long
    Dim nR As Long

    Dim inputType As String
    inputType = TypeName(r)

    ' Update based on comment from jtolle      
    If TypeOf r Is Range Then
        nR = r.Rows.Count
    Else
        nR = UBound(r) - LBound(r) 'r.Rows.Count
    End If
    ' ....
 End Function
```

Comment: could this range be a temporary one, i.e. would it be ok to create a new sheet to hold this range?

Comment: @MikeD - I am trying to avoid writing to a worksheet

Comment: Quick point: 'VarType' applied to an object will return the type of that object's default property if it has one (which 'Range' does - its 'Value' property). If you don't want to use 'TypeName', you can check your argument with 'IsObject' (since that's the only object you'll get when calling your function from the worksheet). There is also the 'TypeOf' operator.

Comment: @jtolle - thanks, I will explore this a bit more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't create a Range object that doesn't in some way reference a worksheet location your workbook. It can be something dynamic, liked a Named =OFFSET() function, for example, but it has to tie back to a worksheet somewhere.

Why not change the interpolation function? Keep your Linterp signature as is, but make it into a wrapper for a function that interpolates on an array.

Something like this:

```
Function Linterp(rng As Range, x As Double) As Double
' R is a two-column range containing known x, known y
' This is now just a wrapper function, extracting the range values into a variant
    Linterp = ArrayInterp(rng.Value, x)

End Function

Function ArrayInterp(r As Variant, x As Double) As Double

Dim lR As Long
Dim l1 As Long, l2 As Long
Dim nR As Long

    nR = UBound(r) ' assumes arrays are all 1-based

    If nR = 1 Then
        ' code as given would return 0, better would be to either return
        ' the only y-value we have (assuming it applies for all x values)
        ' or perhaps to raise an error.
        ArrayInterp = r(1, 2)
        Exit Function
    End If

    If x < r(1, 1) Then ' x < xmin, extrapolate'
        l1 = 1
        l2 = 2
    ElseIf x > r(nR, 2) Then ' x > xmax, extrapolate'
        l2 = nR
        l1 = l2 - 1
    Else
        ' a binary search might be better here if the arrays are large'
        For lR = 1 To nR
            If r(lR, 1) = x Then ' no need to interpolate if x is a point in the array'
                ArrayInterp = r(lR, 2)
                Exit Function
            ElseIf r(lR, 2) > x Then ' x is between tabulated values, interpolate'
                l2 = lR
                l1 = lR - 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If

    ArrayInterp = r(l1, 2) _
           + (r(l2, 2) - r(l1, 2)) _
           * (x - r(l1, 1)) _
           / (r(l2, 1) - r(l1, 1))

End Function
```

Comment: that kinda sucks that a Range object must be tied to a worksheet. I have already implemented a modified Interpolate Function which checks the type of `r` prior to setting the `nR` value. This now works on an Array and Range and can be used in any worksheet as normal.

Comment: the implementation above produces differences in calculated values at the first decimal when compared to two separate interpolate functions

Comment: I have accepted this answer which correctly points out the correct use of the Range object. The second part, which shows an alternate implementation of of Linear Interpolation was not used. Refer to the question for the method used.

Comment: you could always add an intermediate step where you serialise you range object to an xml store or database table.

Answer (score 1):

here's a function to create a range in a new sheet. You can modify this function by adding another range parameter to provide the starting point for the cell range to hold your array.

Put in the code as is at first and walk thru Sub Test() using debugger to see what it can do for you ...

```
Function Array2Range(MyArray() As Variant) As Range
Dim X As Integer, Y As Integer
Dim Idx As Integer, Jdx As Integer
Dim TmpSht As Worksheet, TmpRng As Range, PrevRng As Range

    X = UBound(MyArray, 1) - LBound(MyArray, 1)
    Y = UBound(MyArray, 2) - LBound(MyArray, 2)

    Set PrevRng = Selection
    Set TmpSht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    Set TmpRng = TmpSht.[A1]


    For Idx = 0 To X
        For Jdx = 0 To Y
            TmpRng(Idx + 1, Jdx + 1) = MyArray(LBound(MyArray, 1) + Idx, LBound(MyArray, 2) + Jdx)
        Next Jdx
    Next Idx

    Set Array2Range = TmpRng.CurrentRegion
    PrevRng.Worksheet.Activate

End Function

Sub Test()
Dim MyR As Range
Dim MyArr(3, 3) As Variant

MyArr(0, 0) = "'000"
MyArr(0, 1) = "'0-1" ' demo correct row/column
MyArr(1, 0) = "'1-0" ' demo correct row/column
MyArr(1, 1) = 111
MyArr(2, 2) = 222
MyArr(3, 3) = 333

Set MyR = Array2Range(MyArr) ' to range
Range2Array MyR, MyOther     ' and back

End Sub
```

EDIT =============
ammended sub test() to demo conversion back into array and added quick & dirty piece of code to convert back range into array

```
Sub Range2Array(MyRange As Range, ByRef MyArr() As Variant)
Dim X As Integer, Y As Integer
Dim Idx As Integer, Jdx As Integer
Dim MyArray() As Variant, PrevRng As Range

    X = MyRange.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1
    Y = MyRange.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count - 1
    ReDim MyArr(X, Y)

    For Idx = 0 To X
        For Jdx = 0 To Y
            MyArr(Idx, Jdx) = MyRange(Idx + 1, Jdx + 1)
        Next Jdx
    Next Idx
    MyRange.Worksheet.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the input, it seems based on @Mike Woodhouse, answer, a range object must be tied to a worksheet. The approach you present is somewhat close to what I was just testing out, but I dont think I will be following this approach.