# VBA Creating a worksheet to store data for further range manipulation

Tags: vba, variant

I would like to import a range as a variant with some slight changes to what is stored in the variant, and then export the [modified] variant to a worksheet as a new range, that is then reread back in as a new range where I can do a new set of calculations using excel's built in functions by rereading the range into a new variant

A method describing exports a range to a worksheet can be found here

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SortingArrays.aspx

Under

Sorting Arrays in VBA.

The reason I want to do this is so I can gain access to excel's functions over the data vs having to recode the functions capability in order to use it on an array or variant.

Comment: sorry, the last part of your question is not clear - are you asking how to pass a range reference into a function?

Comment: this is a followup question to an original issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877205/vba-run-worksheetfunction-on-range-derived-variant-array.  I know how to pass a range reference into a function.  What I want to know is how to pass a range into a new worksheet.

Comment: I don't understand too, if you have to write the elements of your array in a new Worksheet you can use single commands or a loop. Else if you need to use excel's built-in function, you can use the WorksheetFunctions...
Can you make your question more clear?

Comment: "if you have to write the elements of your array in a new Worksheet you can use single commands or a loop."  Please tell me how to do this, and immediately reload the data that was exported to a new worksheet as a newly loaded range (just as is done with the cpearson example).

Comment: "if you have to write the elements of your array in a new Worksheet you can use single commands or a loop."  In the cpearson example provided.  Their is data that is held in the original ranged data that is desired to have a "sort" function ran on it.  The only way "sort" can be ran is to export the data to a worksheet, then run sort.  I have a similar issue where I need to export data that is held as a variant to a worksheet, then reload the data as a range, so I can gain access to the sort function.  I need to do this so I can do worksheetfunctions on variant held data.

Comment: this has a nice clear example or copying an array into a range without looping:
http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=157783
obviously you can also return the 'Value' property of a range into a variable using the reverse syntax