# VBA Pass User selected 2d Range vs static array in place of Arr

Tags: vba, variant

I have a need to convert the following function to accept a user selected 2 dimensional range [datatype] in place of Arr [ the arbitrary custom defined Array] that is used in it's place.  I want to do this so I can run worksheet functions on the data.  I know it can be done when the range object is selected, but my data at one points need to be converted to a variant, then re assigned to a [new] range on the new worksheet (aka 'put the array values on the worksheet), then reread back as a range when it does (aka ' load the worksheet values back into the array)

```
Sub SortViaWorksheet()
    Dim Arr(1 To 5) As String ' this is the array to be sorted
    Dim WS As Worksheet ' temporary worksheet
    Dim R As Range
    Dim N As Long

    ' fill up the array with some
    ' aribtrary values.
    Arr(1) = "aaa"
    Arr(2) = "zzz"
    Arr(3) = "mmm"
    Arr(4) = "ttt"
    Arr(5) = "bbb"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' create a new sheet
    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    ' put the array values on the worksheet
    Set R = WS.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(Arr) - LBound(Arr) + 1, 1)
    R = Application.Transpose(Arr)

    ' sort the range
    R.Sort key1:=R, order1:=xlAscending, MatchCase:=False

    ' load the worksheet values back into the array
    For N = 1 To R.Rows.Count
        Arr(N) = R(N, 1)
    Next N

    ' delete the temporary sheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    WS.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ' test/debug/confirmation
    For N = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        Debug.Print Arr(N)
    Next N   
End Sub
```

In other words, I want to be able to pass in a user selected 2d range that will be converted to a variant, then export this variant to a 2d range in a worksheet that is reloaded back into a range for vba to work with and run functions on.  **I understand this example uses .sort, which requires a 1d array.  I do not intend on using sort, but rather things like worksheet functions on this new range, such as rank, countif, average, max, min, median, etc**

My friend pointed out that the example above uses a 1d range as input and exports a 1d array to the worksheet.  So I would need the ability to select a 2d range as input and export a 2d range to a worksheet that is subsequently reread as a new range.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA - Run WorksheetFunction on \[Range derived\] Variant array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877205/vba-run-worksheetfunction-on-range-derived-variant-array)

Comment: your original answer didn't get to the root of the issue.  If I can export a 2d selection to a new worksheet and reload the worksheet into a new range, I can run excel functions on them.

Comment: Well you gave up on that question -- I was engaged in the comments with you, trying to fully understand the problem. Next thing I know you have asked 2 more questions which are essentially part of the same original problem.  What specific part has you stuck?

Comment: You have `Set R = ..` and `R=` in consecutive lines thus overwriting the first statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a worksheet range to an array and back again using the range's `Value` property.  For example to read the current workbook selection into an array, process it, and write it back:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim myArr() As Variant
    myArr = Selection.Value

    For i = LBound(myArr, 1) To UBound(myArr, 1)
        For j = LBound(myArr, 2) To UBound(myArr, 2)
            myArr(i, j) = myArr(i, j) + 5
            Debug.Print CStr(i) & "_" & CStr(j) & ": " & myArr(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

    Selection = myArr
End Sub
```

To pass the range into a function for processing:

```
Sub TestMain()
    Selection = TestProcess(Selection)
End Sub

Function TestProcess(userRange As Range) As Variant
    Dim result() As Variant

    result = userRange.Value

    For i = LBound(result, 1) To UBound(result, 1)
        For j = LBound(result, 2) To UBound(result, 2)
            result(i, j) = result(i, j) + 5
            Debug.Print CStr(i) & "_" & CStr(j) & ": " & result(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

    TestProcess = result
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do for example:

```
Public Sub ProcessRange(ByRef r As Range)
    Dim vals() As Variant
    vals = r.Value
    Dim rows As Integer, cols As Integer
    rows = r.rows.Count: cols = r.Columns.Count
    Dim x As Double
    x = WorksheetFunction.Average(vals)
    ' 3.66666
End Sub
```

when called by `ProcessRange Range("B4").Resize(3, 3)` in [image: SCR]